# How to query multiple matching items through join sql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

First of all, sorry for the poorly worded question. I just cant find a way on how I can say what I really want to say. In any case, what I am trying to accomplish is a table that shows the gender, activity, and count of users for each activity for each gender group.

My query currently looks like this

```
select count(a.activity), b.gender, a.activity 
from access a left join account b on a.email = b.email 
where gender like 'bigender' 
group by activity;
```

This returns a table with each activity and its count alongside the gender the where clause has. In this case it is bigender. While this works for single gender selections, I cant figure out a way to include all genders in the query.

Comment: Unless you're using a case-sensitive collation (unlikely), LIKE does nothing useful for you here.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT b.gender, COUNT(a.activity) AS countOfactivity 
FROM access a 
LEFT JOIN account b ON a.email = b.email 
GROUP BY bigender;
```